# Two GH Pages site on the same domain

Tags: google-search-console, url, github-pages

I have one GH Pages website at the URL `username.github.io/project-name`, which has a dedicated purpose. This has been around for some time, so I don't want to change its URL.

I then setup a second website at `username.github.io`, which would be my personal site (blogging, for example). I do not want this to be a /project-name situation, the root page of the domain should be the index for this site.

However, Google Search Console seems to treat the first site as a part of the second. Is there any way to keep them separate?

Comment: Technically speaking, the first 'site' is part of the larger site. It is within the root structure of your github site.

Comment: @A_Patterson Yes, but that is what I want to "undo." Any tips? GH only gives you one domain

Comment: Buy a cheap domain and hook your GH pages to a netlify account. Or setup another GH account with the dedicated purpose of acting as your blog platform.

Comment: I moved it to Netlify @A_Patterson. Thanks!